# Show that the sphere s(0,1) is closed set .

Tags: real-analysis

Let (R,d) be the metric space where

d(x,y)=|x−y|∀x,y∈R

Show that the sphere s(0,1) is closed set .

Answer (score 0):

To show that the sphere is closed, you want to show that its complement is open. Let us denote the n-sphere by $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $. We want to show that for any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - S^n$, there is an open ball contained entirely in this complement. Let $d = d(x,0)$. Then note that if $d < 1$, then the ball of radius $(1-d)$ around $x$ lies entirely in the complement. If $d>1$ then the ball of radius $(d-1)$ around $x$ lies entirely in the complement. Note that if $d=1$ then it is actually on the sphere and not in the complement. So $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - S^n$ is open $ \implies S^n$ is closed.

Edit: Note that this can be extended to any sphere around any point and of any radius. Since any sphere around any other point is a composition of a scaling and a translation, both of which are continuous, and the continuous image of a closed set is closed, any sphere around any point of arbitrary radius is closed.

Edit 2: This is the proof of the case $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. Note that $S$ = {-1,1}. Now, $\mathbb{R}-S$ = $(-\infty,-1) \cup (-1,1) \cup (1,\infty)$ i.e. it is the union of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Since a union of open sets is open, $\mathbb{R}-S$ is open $\implies$ $S$ is closed.

Comment: What is the n next to S and R ?

Comment: The dimension in which we're working. So for example, the sphere in 3-dimensions is the 2-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Your question doesn't define what dimension sphere we're working with. Is it the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Is it the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$? In general, the n-sphere is set of unit vectors in n+1 Euclidean space, so the n is an arbitrary dimension.

Comment: If it's a complement why not to write it with out the n

Comment: It says it's  in R

Comment: Ah my apologies, I didn't see that. The proof still works, just replace n with 1 everywhere (or ignore it all together). Of course you could just note that if the space is $\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ = {-1,1}. So the complement is $(-\infty, -1) \cup (-1,1)  \cup (1, \infty)$ which is open as the union of open sets.

Comment: How come s = -1,1

Comment: The standard definition of a sphere is the unit vectors in the space, which here is -1 and 1. Does your question refer to a different sphere, such as [-1,1]?

Comment: In the question it says S(0,1)

Comment: I interpreted that that to mean the sphere centred at 0 and of radius 1, which is indeed {-1,1}.

Comment: Where did -1 come from

Comment: What is at a distance of 1 from the origin? I can go left one unit (and end up at -1) or go right one unit (and end up at 1).

Comment: okay , so the solution would start of proving that the complement is is open then say that S subset from R , then .. ?

Comment: Refer to my second edit that I just posted

Comment: what dose i.e mean

Comment: my last question is , we mean by the complement all R except S right ? So why did you union all the interval even the S {-1,1} , I thought we should take the S of ? Am confused

Comment: i.e. means that is. If you remove the points -1 and 1 from $\mathbb{R}$, what you are left with is the union of those 3 intervals.